# X11 installation in ECLIPSE

Tags: c, eclipse, x11, xlib

I have been trying to install X11 in Eclipse for C. I have to design visualization applications in C using X11. I am used to Eclipse for java. I need your help for the detailed steps to get X11 directory and getting Xlib.h, xatom.h,xos.h,xutil.h file access through eclipse.

I have been trying very hard but not able to find suitable answer. I like Eclipse because its easy to debug and I have windows operating system.

Please suggest me how can I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X11 is a windowing system widely used on Linux and Unix systems. You have 2 options:

1. Go native and install you favorite Linux distro, either as a VM or on actual hardware, then install eclipse on that.
2. Try using Cygwin. Cygwin allows you to run *nix apps on Windows and X server is one of the apps supported.You can find more info on http://x.cygwin.com/

Comment: I have also a doubt like after installing xserver how can I actually configure X11 libraries in eclipse. Whats the path for those libraries? I am sorry I'm very new for X11 and its confusing.

Comment: You can configure eclipse quite easily actually. There is plenty of documentation how to do that, but basically all you have to do is to se the C++ project properties and  include paths. You can post another question for that, but this should get you started: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm

Comment: X11 is not a window manager. It's a windowing system that comes without a built-in window manager. There are many window managers that work with X11.

Comment: Agreed. I'll reword it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do C/C++ development then you need to install the [Eclipse CDT package](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).  This allows you to create a C/C++ project inside of eclipse in which you can then write your X11 program.

If you are doing Java development, then you don't use X11 or even Windows.h directly, instead you use the [Java Swing framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to do your graphical UIs.  When run on an X11 based system (unix) it will use X11 underneath to render the display, while on a carbon based system (OSX) it will use Carbon and on a Windows system it will use windows api.

However, you also mention you are using the "windows operating system" and if by that you mean Microsoft Windows, then there is no (practical) way to do X11 development on windows.  You really need to stop and think about what you are trying to achieve and perhaps post a different question about how you can accomplish that.

Comment: Actually he should be able to use Cygwin.

Comment: You're free to try and explain doing Cygwin development on windows using eclipse.  I'm not going down that rabbit hole.  That's why I said there is no "practical" way of doing it.

Comment: Hi I installed that CDT package already in eclipse(windows operating system). I can write hello world programs or other pointer related programs. But when I copied the code from my senior relating to find shortest path algorithm using X11 libs like #include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

Comment: I am getting errors. Can you please suggest me whats the best way to write x11 programs. I used cygwin and downloaded X11 but not able to proceed further as I was not able to run startx, and with Linux can I run better? do i HAVE TO INSTALL eclipse in linux for debugging? I want to debug this code in C.

Comment: I think we need to figure out what are you trying to achieve - you sound confused and it's possible that we are talking passed each other. Did someone assign you this task? Do they want the application to work on Windows, Linux or both? Did they indicate what OS to use for the development?

Comment: Operating system is not specific, I want to find which one is easy to use.